# What't the end flag of google-speech-to-text-api?

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am using google speech to text api.
I am using StreamingRecognizeRequest and setting "InterimResults" true.
Now I want to know what's the end flag of the response?
I notice there is a "isFinal" flag,but it seems to be the end of one sentence. In one requesting, it may Appear many times.
So, what't the end flag in the StreamingRecognitionResult ?

Here is my request setting,and response from server.
[request setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CYgr.png)

[response struct from google server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbE0.png)

Comment: Hi @cnskt, which programming language are you using?